# slice lowest positive value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset looking like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), days=c(100, 10, -8, -5, 12, 10))
```

Now I only want to take the lowest positive value of "days" so that my output would look like this:

```
new <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 2, 3), days=c(10, 12, 10))
```

I have thought about this:

```
df%>%
group_by(ID)%>%
slice_min(days)
```

But of course this will return the lowest number number also if it is negative. What can I do to only get the **lowest** **positive** values?

Preferably using dplyr.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filtering only positve values for days should do.

```r
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), days=c(100, 10, -8, -5, 12, 10))
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(days>0) %>% 
  slice_min(days)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>      ID  days
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    10
#> 2     2    12
#> 3     3    10
```

Comment: Why do you place the `filter` after the `group_by`-statement? Just curious.

Comment: good question... to the best of my knowledge, it does not matter in this and similar cases. filter could be placed before as well. (in big datasets, there might be some performance difference, I am not sure).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aggregate()`

```
aggregate(days ~ ID, df, function(x){
  min(x[x > 0])
})

#   ID days
# 1  1   10
# 2  2   12
# 3  3   10
```